# Do you need to upgrade both states if one refers to the other in a contract

Tags: corda

Scenario: I have `contractV1` cordapp with `ObligationV1` and `CashV1`.
In the `Obligation.Settle` command, it enforces that `ObligationV1` and `CashV1` must be consumed to settle an obligation.

Assume there's a need to upgrade `CashV1` and `CashContractV1` to V2. 
Because Obligation contract had some dependencies on the `CashV1` state, does it mean I have to bump the `ObligationContractV1` to V2 so it could enforce that CashV2 must be consumed during Settle command? There's no need to upgrade Obligation state, because nothing changes?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have written `ObligationContractV1` in such a way that it is tightly coupled to `CashV1`, then yes - you'll have to upgrade `ObligationContractV1` too.

However, it would be best to have an abstract `Cash` interface that all `CashVX` states implement. Then in the `ObligationContractV1`, you can simply enforce that one of the states is of type `Cash`. Your contract is then not tightly coupled to a specific `Cash` version.